# Can we show that $\frac1{2^n}\lceil2^nx\rceil\downarrow x$ for $n\to\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions, monotone-functions

Let $x\in\mathbb R$ and $$\tilde x_n:=\frac1{2^n}\lfloor2^nx\rfloor\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N\;.$$ It's easy to show that $\tilde x_n\uparrow x$ for $n\to\infty$. Now, let $$x_n:=\frac1{2^n}\lceil2^nx\rceil\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N\;.$$ Can we analogously show that $x_n\downarrow x$ for $n\to\infty$? I've tried to use $$x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor\le x\le\lceil x\rceil<x+1\tag 1$$ together with the assumption $$2^nx=k+\delta\tag 2$$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$ and $\delta\in[0,1)$. With this approach I was able to show $\tilde x_n\le\tilde x_{n+1}$, but I wasn't able to show $x_n\ge x_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

$$x_n - x_{n+1} = \frac{2\lceil 2^n x\rceil - \lceil 2^{n+1}x\rceil}{2^{n+1}} \geqslant 0$$

since $2\lceil y\rceil \geqslant \lceil 2y\rceil$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: And how do you prove $2\lceil y\rceil\ge\lceil 2y\rceil$?

Comment: Write $y = k - \delta$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \leqslant \delta < 1$. Then $\lceil y\rceil = k$, and $2\lceil y\rceil = 2k \geqslant 2y = 2k - 2\delta$. You even see that you have equality if and only if $\delta < 1/2$.